# Unsure why this is bad sql syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running the `pgsanity` postgresql syntax checker (for reference `pgsanity` leverages the ecpg command to find syntax errors) over a file, `foo.sql`, written by someone else. It begins with these lines:

```
--##############################################################################
-- DROP Existing function
--##############################################################################
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS schema_name.presumably_a_function_name(text);

--##############################################################################
-- Create track duplicate rate function
--##############################################################################
```

And I get the error message `line 4: ERROR: unrecognized data type name "`. I am very much a novice to sql, so am unsure what this error message means. Any help deciphering would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like some kind of templating. Do you use some tool to generate SQL code?

Comment: Apologies. I put those in there to indicate I had replaced the text with something generic

Comment: Why the "(text)" part?

Comment: That is a valid SQL statement and works just fine - how exactly are you running that? I guess whatever tool you are using is not sending _that_ statement to the Postgres server

Comment: @Carra: because you need to specify the function signature in Postgres to drop  a function. The syntax shown references a function with exactly one parameter of type `text`. This is necessary because there could be multiple, overloaded functions with that name.

Comment: BTW: formally `--###` should be `-- ###` . (but most parser will accept a `--` comment without a trailing space)